# In my situation, how could I learn to program without a mentor?

Tags: c++, productivity, code-reviews

So my problem may be relatively rare, at least the majority of the "how to learn to code" questions I've come across deal with a lack of fundamental understanding of computers or languages. I'm fluent in Linux, repairing PC's to an extent, learning new languages is not a problem for me (learned a bit of Scheme to hand in lab assignments in a single day), etc. I've been in the KDE open source project and fixed bugs and segfaults successfully, though the latter required some assistance since I lacked the necessary OS knowledge. **But**, there's a huge problem.

I can't write code from scratch, especially in my favorite C++ language.I  understand the language itself, no problems. Whenever I have to design a set of classes for my program (a very simple one), to break down responsibilities between functions, to choose a language or a library feature to use among the ones available, I come to a stall and spend days starting at the damn screen. I have a great PC, display, and soon a new keyboard. I have a lot of time, yet it's wasted wandering around, unable to make a choice or design decision. The essence of the problem is probably that I don't know what is more correct or appropriate, and, importantly, what is the "common" way to do this or that - I don't want to reinvent the wheel or take the wrong aproach - see the last paragraph for why it is so.

The root as I feel it is here: I'm in a dire need of input on my ideas, for them to be validated or rejected, or at least discussed. My university, and no Russian university for that matter (or no Uni in the world? how is it done in the West?) doesn't offer such a "consulting" service, and no one actually cares for the actual code I write. Yesterday I learn that once a course is over, I'm not allowed to ask that professor for help on projects, which is understandable since they have finite amount of free time and students are many. I learned English with a very, very great teacher, who taught me to actually speak instead of just knowing the grammar. Maybe I can or should find a mentor to get me through the stalls in the beginning?

How can I solve this? How do all those people who post code on GitHub write it in the first place, obviously there's no validation or review for personal projects?

In case you wonder where it stems from, in my mathematical school we were taught to act on probems in a "literate fashion" and areceive feedback, as well as follow the established rules and practices. However, I still managed to find my own solutions, and they were of course accepted. But with this programming problem I'm describing, I feel I simply don't know enough rules or examples to follow..

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the downvoters left comments or observations.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but career/education advice is off-topic on this site, which is probably the reason.

Comment: @Ixrec which site is more appropriate? This is about programming, how to learn programming, so I think it belongs to the site called "programmers", doesn't it?

Comment: The name is unfortunately very misleading (and we have no control over it). This site is primarily about software design and engineering questions. Things like how to learn programming, what languages to use, what projects to do, what jobs to take are considered off-topic. I'm not aware of any StackExchange site on which this particular question would be considered on-topic or answerable, though I can't speak for Productivity.SE.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post on Quora, I've made a promise not to sign up for that for the suspicious content that they mail in the digest. SO I have to find an SE site where this questions fits. The university won't help me either, sicne they dont' care for programming, rather the actual science.

Comment: That's a shame. Quora is exactly the sort of site where this question would normally do very well.

Comment: Well I know, but let's hope the experienced programmers in here can give a decent bit of advice as well.

Comment: If you have running code and want input on that you could just post it on codereview.stackexchange.com. Not sure what exactly the rules there are (must run, it's not about debugging) but in many cases it should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @thorstenmüller indeed, I've thought about that, but I can't post the whole program there, nor can I abuse that place on and on, it's simply too many questions. They arise every.. minute, half an hour, hour, whatever. Guess it takes someone sitting by my side to put an end to this.

Comment: Sorry, but off-topic is off-topic whether you have an alternative in mind or not. This site is for _software design_ questions; as with any website, its scope is not simply defined by the few characters making up its domain name and you should read the Help Centre to find out what we're actually all about.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet where do you think I should move this? productivity.se.com? Edit: oh it's you mate. hello, you change nicks every other day.. =]

Comment: There are a lot of parallels between learning to program and learning to speak a second (natural) language, or learning all sorts of other things such as playing a musical instrument.   You might find this page interesting/reassuring:  [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)

Comment: "There's no place to get personal projects reviewed." Well, that's just not true. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RubberDuck how often and how much can I post there so it's polite and inside bounds so to say?

Comment: @iksemyonov just poke around our FAQ & meta prior to posting and you'll be fine. Our biggest caveat is that the code works, it's *real* (not simplified MVCEs like other SE sites), and the code must be included in the question (not just a link to some off site repository).

Comment: @iksemyonov: Sounds like you have "fear of the white paper". It might be because you are too perfectionist and are afraid to start something "the wrong way". Rather than focusing on doing thinks the "right way" from the beginning, start with focusing on finding the simplest solution and getting the code to work as soon a possible, however ugly it might be. You can always refine later as you learn more. Software is usually developed iteratively, where code gets gradually better in each revision.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Blogs and podcasts are your mentors.  Books are your mentors.  Videos are your mentors.  The Internet has made it possible to have these things in abundance.  Pursue them with vigor.**

I know this is going to make me sound like an old-timer, but when I was your age I didn't have any mentors.  There were no mentors, because they didn't exist.  The Internet didn't exist.  Good programming classes didn't exist.  All that was available to me was my intellect and a computer.  I knew more than anyone else around me at the time.  That's not a boast; it's just the way it was.  The only possible mentors would have been Bill Gates, Steve Jobs or Steve Wozniak, but I'm pretty sure none of those guys was going to come over to my house and teach me how to program.

So here's the deal.  Until you've written, tested, debugged,refactored and rewritten, say, a hundred thousand lines of code in an actual application, **your code is going to suck**.  You have to figure out what works and what doesn't, in the moment, while you're writing code.  In that way, it's no different than learning a musical instrument; you have to put in the practice.

Certainly, I do encourage you to read books, listen to podcasts and watch videos.  They will teach you the basic principles.  But none of those tools are going to teach you how to program until you practice programming by writing lots of good code.  And here's the rub: **nobody is going to mentor you until you know the fundamentals,** which you can get without supervised instruction, if you happen to be talented enough to be a programmer.

A cautionary note: **don't get too wrapped up in rules, "best practices" or software patterns** until you understand the fundamentals of programming well enough to understand why these maxims exist.  If you've never written any code, it's too soon to study the Single Responsibility Principle, because you're not going to understand it and you're going to misapply it.  Don't get sucked into the "software patterns" craze too early.  If you have to ask "which hammer should I use to fix this roof," then you don't know enough yet to fix the roof.

And finally, a warning:  If you're getting into programming for any reason other than to love it and be the best you can possibly be at it (reasons such as money, lifestyle, etc.), you will be miserable and you will make everyone around you miserable.  Programming is aggravating enough without it being a calling, and there are too many marginal programmers out there already.  Do the world a favor and **be good at it, or don't do it at all.**

Comment: So it's not as off-topic after all, as it may seem =] OK, i'm going to read this a few times until it makes sense. There is some real though put into this, and experience too. One think that really susprises me is the "best of quit altogether" - there are so many programmers, and godo ones at that, isn't this like saying "when starting to learn teh guitar, think about becoming Iommi"? I've grown up in an environment with a motto of "don't think you just can go and do it, it's harder than that", maybe it's what's killing me, too.

Comment: Learning guitar in your bedroom for your own pleasure is not the same.  Your chance of becoming a professional musician and making any real money at it is vanishingly small compared to programming.  If you apply yourself and become good at software development, money should never be a problem.  And yes, you absolutely can do it, but don't think you can just skate.

Comment: By the way, when you were starting out with programming, you were so few and there was so much to do yet! Lok at the programming world nowadays, isn't it different and "over-stuffed" so to say\?

Comment: It is quite different, yes.  But I actually had a detailed discussion yesterday with my boss about that.  Overblown architectures are on their way out.  Microservices are the new black.

Comment: By that example, I simply meant that chances of becoming the best or just very very good in any field are marginally small, aren't they?

Comment: There will be more openings for software developers in the next 15 years than there are qualified people to fill them.  Getting a job is not going to be a problem, *if you're good.*  See http://www.bls.gov/ooh/computer-and-information-technology/software-developers.htm

Comment: And, what would you say, can I have an opinion different than a professor's who is a seasoned developer? Or can I jsut do it differently and not feel this terrible guilt. Edit: Oh I'm in Russia but I hope it's the same and that one day I'll be able to do remote form home.

Comment: What terrible guilt?  If your professor is a typical professor, he's *not a seasoned developer.*  He's just a smart guy who's teaching programming from a textbook.  There's a reason that the phrase "Those who don't do, teach" is funny: it has the ring of truth to it.  Stop measuring yourself against other people; *they don't matter to your potential career as a programmer.*  What matters is your ability to work with other people and get things done.

Comment: Well, thing is some are really developers wityh experience in huge projects. But Ihear you. I need to be more sure about my choices. Somehow.

Comment: You do that by practicing more and getting better every day.  Don't expect it to happen tomorrow, or the next day, or the next week.  Very likely it will take years.  But if you make the decision to apply yourself and do not waver, you'll look back on those years as some of the best times of your life, and realize that it wasn't so hard after all.

Comment: Hell, even "seasoned developers" make awful decisions. I just interviewed a guy with 20+ yrs of experience. Afterwards, I told our Jr. "Congrats mate. You're a better dev than *that* guy."

Comment: OK, makes sense =] One more then.. if 99% of the students around use VS and Win, and I'm on linux with vim in a screen and a handwritten makefile.. should I care? I have this probably silly thought of "must be a reason why noone does it" or "you're just showing off".

Comment: @RubberDuck well the person I have in mind is really great as a person and a teacher, so doesn't apply here, with al due respect. I just need to ber more confident. Edit: Ah and i'm 24 =[ Not too late?

Comment: RE: Linux... Respectfully, that's your ego talking.  Chuck the ego, and just do what you need to do to become a great software developer.

Comment: @iksemyonov I didn't become a professional until I was 25-26. It was only a once in a few years hobby until then. No. It's not too late.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ego about vim right? mean I started using it just to learn it becuase so many linux users claim one should be able to use that and as a challenge to see if I could do it. And I'm really more comfortable in Linux as a dev platform than Win with all the libraries available in one command of a package manager.

Comment: I'll just add one more thing.  When I first started programming, there were always long periods where I was just sitting at the keyboard trying to figure out what to do next.  I still have those periods sometimes.  I think that's normal.

Comment: Believe it or not, I know where to go next half the time, but I can't choose if e.g. it's going to be a class, three classes, or a bit of stl tucked into a function.. such stuff. Oh and of course I spend a lot of time staring into the screen..

Comment: Go back and read everything I just wrote again.

Comment: Sure, I mentioned it would take time to sink in. Thank you for the valuable input.

Comment: @iksemyonov: if you have choices to choose from, you're already quite ahead. Just pick one at random, try it, see where it leads you. If it leads you to a bad place, retrace your steps and take a different path. In the beginning you don't have the intuition yet to predict the consequences of a particular choice, so don't even try to. The way to develop that insight is to build it wrong over and over again, until you develop enough intuition to get it right from the first time.

Comment: @iksemyonov, preferring Linux, Vim and makefiles to MS and VS doesn't *by itself* make you a good programmer, but it does immediately give me the *impression* that you're more likely to know what you're doing.  Regarding: *"must be a reason why no one does it,"* —there may be reasons, but none of them have anything to do with inherently superior technical quality of MS and VS.  That may be my personal bias but I'm still right.  ;)